# Dispalying pictures from database in xaml

Tags: c#, image, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I write image in local database.

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
WriteableBitmap mywbq = new WriteableBitmap(bmp);
mywbq.SaveJpeg(stream, mywbq.PixelWidth, mywbq.PixelHeight, 0, 95);
byte[] imagearray = stream.ToArray();
stream.Close();
db._contacts.InsertOnSubmit(new MyContactsList {ItemImage = imagearray });
db.SubmitChanges();
```

And I want this picture display in xaml.
How it's impossible?

I use it [source](http://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCUQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fwindowsphone%2Fdevelop%2Fhh286418(v%3Dvs.105).aspx&ei=irfYU-isGsmC4gSHooGwDA&usg=AFQjCNHrgBnoEouAeOa8vhEzbSYlzcKXjg&bvm=bv.71778758,d.bGE)

But this class doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple as that:

```
byte[] yourImageBytesFromDatabase = ......;
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
ms.Write(yourImageBytesFromDatabase, 0, yourImageBytesFromDatabase.Length);
BitmapImage src = new BitmapImage();
src.SetSource(ms);
```